# Буква "фита"

Tags: фонетика

Какой звук означала в русском языке буква "фита" и зачем она была нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку кириллица вообще имеет много общего с греческим алфавитом, то и фита попала в него оттуда. В греческом языке это буква тета, которая означает звук, аналогичесный английскому глухому [th]. Но так как в русском языке такого звука нет, то ее принято было читать как Ф, а писалась фита в словах греческого происхождения - чаще всего в именах. Выглядела фита как перечеркнутое О - **Ɵ**.
Примеры: ***Ɵ**едор, **Ɵ**илипп*.

Именно поэтому в других языках есть разночтения в произношении этих имен. Сравните украинское:* Тодор (Теодор), Пилип*.